# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n$ is cyclic if $n$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

I'm starting doing my Group theory's course problems, and I'm having trouble with this one:

> Consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n$ of the units
> of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n$ is
> cyclic if n is prime.

The notation used means $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_n=\{r\in\mathbb{Z}_n:\exists s\in\mathbb{Z}_n \text{ s.t } rs=1=sr\}$. I guess it will have somewhat to do with Euler's $\phi$ function. I first suppose $n$ prime, but know what's the next step. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe even if $n$ is not prime?

Comment: There is no $n$ in my comment. The result I stated is general, and in your case, you could apply it to the field $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (which is indeed a field iff $n$ is prime).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks for the comment. So the question of the problem does not have sense right?

Comment: This is not what I mean ! The question has sense. What I say is that the statement you have to prove is a particular case of a much general statement, which is the one of my first comment. If you know this result, you can apply it to get your result easily. If you don't, then you have to think differently :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Oh I understand now. Thank you so much for the help!